# How to assign separate titles to multiple plots

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using the glob.glob function to read all excel files in a folder, I am outputing multiple plots (one for each excel file in the folder).  I'd like to put a unique title on each plot, using a portion of each file name as the title.  When I run this code, it will plot the data of each unique plot correctly but the title always ends up being from the last excel file in this list.  How to I make sure the title is grabbing from every excel file name, rather than just the last?

```
path = "C:\\Users\\mgphi\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Research\\Cascades\\Profiles\\Error reporting\\cpx"

#Find all .xlsx files in given path
filenames = glob.glob(path+'\\*.xlsx')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))

titles = str(filenames[i].split('\\')[-1])[0:7]
for i in range(0,len(filenames)):
    years = np.asarray(pd.read_excel(filenames[i]))[:,0]
    pdf = np.asarray(pd.read_excel(filenames[i]))[:,1]
    #print(filenames[i].split('\\')[-1])
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(years,pdf)
    plt.ylim(0,.00006)
    plt.title(titles)
    plt.xlabel('years modeled')
    plt.ylabel('1/misfit')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should define "titles" in the for-loop.

Comment: Awesome, that worked just the way I wanted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As what @Michael Butscher has suggested:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\mgphi\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Research\\Cascades\\Profiles\\Error reporting\\cpx"

#Find all .xlsx files in given path
filenames = glob.glob(path+'\\*.xlsx')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))

for i in range(0,len(filenames)):
    titles = str(filenames[i].split('\\')[-1])[0:7]
    years = np.asarray(pd.read_excel(filenames[i]))[:,0]
    pdf = np.asarray(pd.read_excel(filenames[i]))[:,1]
    #print(filenames[i].split('\\')[-1])
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(years,pdf)
    plt.ylim(0,.00006)
    plt.title(titles)
    plt.xlabel('years modeled')
    plt.ylabel('1/misfit')
plt.show()
```

Also somewhat related, which I find possibly useful for your case, you may want to utilize [Snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) if you are generating a lot of such plots. So rather than searching for the filenames, you use Snakemake to provide the filenames rather than leave it within the script for easier debugging.